# Error when use auto_increment in MySQL

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I meet some errors when using `auto_increment` in MySQL.

code is here:

```
user_id bigint(20) unsigned not null auto_increment=1000
```

but when I try

```
user_id bigint(20) unsigned not null auto_increment
```

it works. why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
create table test1 (
id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
primary key (id)
)auto_increment=100;
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to seed the auto increment number?

If so, the syntax is part of the `CREATE|ALTER TABLE` command.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: I want to set a start value 1000 when `create` table use first code, but it's wrong.

Comment: @MYBot Please look at the documentation again. In [`CREATE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html), you seed the auto increment value *after* the `create_definition` in the `table_options` section.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because auto increment is set for the table and not a particular column.
So to start from 1000,
Create a table column with just  `auto_increment`

And then alter the table using

```
ALTER TABLE your_table_name AUTO_INCREMENT=1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

auto increment of mysql is only +1 value.

look at this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: I want a start vaule `1000`, not +1000